# How to remove carriage return from a variable in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to shell script. I am sourcing a file, which is created in Windows and has carriage returns, using the `source` command. After I source when I append some characters to it, it always comes to the start of the line.

`test.dat` (which has carriage return at end):

```
testVar=value123
```

`testScript.sh` (sources above file):

```
source test.dat
echo $testVar got it
```

The output I get is

```
got it23
```

How can I remove the `'\r'` from the variable?

Comment: When you've written a Linux script in Windows, you need to convert the whole file so that all of the carriage returns are removed before running it, otherwise you will run into all sorts of problems. Attempting to replace individual carriage returns might fix some problems, but others will appear. For me it was often with messages about lines that were truncated. Thus, it is best to convert the whole file using a program like `dos2unix`.

Comment: Its an old one ofcourse, but this oneliner should do too.

`echo ${testVar%'\r'}`

Answer (score 92):

yet another solution uses `tr`:

```
echo $testVar | tr -d '\r'
cat myscript | tr -d '\r'
```

the option `-d` stands for `delete`.

Comment: This helps but it's removing the last word/character for me.

Comment: @Clover, can u please provide an example? I think there is something else hiding

Answer (score 32):

You can use sed as follows:

```
MY_NEW_VAR=$(echo $testVar | sed -e 's/\r//g')
echo ${MY_NEW_VAR} got it
```

By the way, try to do a `dos2unix` on your data file.

Comment: I implemented this and it deletes every "r" not just carriage returns.

Comment: Are you sure you kept the \ ?

Answer (score 27):

Because the file you source ends lines with carriage returns, the contents of `$testVar` are likely to look like this:

```
$ printf '%q\n' "$testVar"
$'value123\r'
```

(The first line's `$` is the shell prompt; the second line's `$` is from the `%q` formatting string, indicating [`$''` quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).)

To get rid of the carriage return, you can use [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) (requires Bash):

```
testVar=${testVar//$'\r'}
```

Which should result in

```
$ printf '%q\n' "$testVar"
value123
```

Comment: I needed \n instead of \r ... for some reason

Comment: @DavidGoodwin Weird. What does the output of `printf '%q\n' "$testVar"` look like?

Comment: $'include:(\n  .......blah blah .... )\n)'
(My multiline string was made from 
```sh
VAR=$(cat <<EOF
include:(
    .... blah blah .....
EOF
)
```

Comment: @DavidGoodwin But do you even have carriage returns you want to remove?

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaah :lightbulb: etc. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for this thread. I spent one hour pulling my hair because I was reading a Windows file into a Bash variable and the result was total nonsense. `testVar=${testVar//$'\r'}` did the trick.

Answer (score 8):

use this command on your script file after copying it to Linux/Unix

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r//' scriptfilename
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for `perl`. I couldn't download `dos2unix`, `tr` wouldn't work and what not! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I used `perl -p -e 's/\r\n$//' ` to trim `\r\n` from only the end of the input.

Answer (score 6):

Pipe to `sed -e 's/[\r\n]//g'` to remove both Carriage Returns (`\r`) and Line Feeds (`\n`) from each text line.

Comment: You cannot remove `\n` using sed like that.  See http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq5.html#s5.10

Answer (score 5):

for a pure shell solution without calling external program:

```
NL=$'\n'    # define a variable to reference 'newline'

testVar=${testVar%$NL}    # removes trailing 'NL' from string
```

Comment: The problem is the carriage return, not the newline, though.

Comment: so NL=$'\n' and NR=$'\r' and replace both, nothing happens on a no find condition