# Script to check if a webpage has changed

Tags: bash

I have an assigment and i have to read a list of websites from a text file (sites.txt) and check if any of them have static changes since the last time i run the script. My input is

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds
```

If any of the websites is down it should print to stderr the name of the address and the message FAILED like this output example.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow FAILED
```

Also if the input text file contains # it should ignore the line as a comment. My attempt was to create 2 html files old.html and new.html and check in an if statement if the subtraction of the html files is different than 0. My problem is that my output is strangely different than i expected and that the curl command always assumes that the websites are down. The output i have is:

```
 FAILED/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow
 FAILED/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds FAILED
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    [[ "$line" = "\#*" ]] && continue
    if [ "$(curl -s --head  --request GET "$line" | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null)" ]; then
        mv new.html old.html 2> /dev/null
        curl "$line" -L --compressed -s > new.html 
        DIFF_OUTPUT="$(diff new.html old.html)"
        if [ "0" != "${#DIFF_OUTPUT}" ]; then
            echo "$line Changed"
        fi  
    else
        echo "$line FAILED" >&2
    fi
done <"$1"
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You might want to do a HEAD request and consider the Last-Modified header.

Comment: `curl -s -I 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow' | grep '^Last-Modified:'`

Comment: Thank you for your answers.I was writing my code on Git bash on windows and when i changed to linux terminal the output was correct.My only problem now is that the curl command always assumes tha the sites are down which they're not.Got any hints?

Answer (score 1):

`sites.txt` has DOS line endings `\r\n` rather than UNIX line endings `\n`. The `\r` carriage returns cause the cursor to move back to the first column. You need to either [convert `sites.txt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-lf-in-a-bash-script) [to UNIX format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix) or [delete the carriage returns from `$line`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520339/how-to-remove-carriage-return-and-newline-from-a-variable-in-shell-script).

Answer (score -2):

```
LINK="https://www.google.com"


if [ "$(curl -s --head  --request GET "$LINK" | grep "200 OK" | wc -l)" ]; then
    echo "okey"
else
    echo "FALSE"
fi
```

Comment: It's ok to offer workarounds on debugging questions, but please try to offer some insight as to why the code isn't working.