# Shell script error message - 1")syntax error: operand expected (error token is "

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
     if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
         echo Enter operand1 value:
         read operand1
 
         # Offer choices
         echo 1. Addition
         echo 2. Subtraction
         echo 3. Multiplication
         echo 4. Division
         echo 5. Exit
 
         echo Enter your choice:
         read choice
 
         echo Enter operand2 value:
         read operand2
 
         # get operands and start computing based on the user's choice
         if [[ $choice -eq 1 ]] ; then
 
 
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo Addition of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1+operand2))
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo
         elif [[ $choice -eq 2 ]] ; then
 
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo Subtraction of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1-operand2))
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo
         elif [[ $choice -eq 3 ]] ; then
 
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo Multiplication of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1*operand2))
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo
         elif [[ $choice -eq 4 ]] ; then
 
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo Division of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1/operand2))
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo
         elif [[ $choice -eq 5 ]] ; then
             exit
         else
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo Invalid choice.. Please try again
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo
         fi
    
   else
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo You either passed too many parameters or too less
             echo than the optimum requirement.
             echo
             echo This program accepts a maximum of 2 arguments or no
             echo argument at all in order to run successfully.
             echo ----------------------------------------
   fi
done
```

I keep getting error message `1")syntax error: operand expected (error token is "`.

Would someone be able to help me out with why I am getting this message a possible work around?

Comment: Exactly where are you getting this error?

Comment: The error message suggest that your file has dos line endings. Remove them.

Comment: That looks like a CR indeed, but I can't see where that exact error would come from. Can you show how you run the script and how it gets its input?

Answer (score 0):

Based on how the error message is messed up (assuming you did copy it exactly), it looks like you're getting a carriage return from somewhere. If the problematic token was `\r1`, the error would print as

```
...syntax error: operand expected (error token is "\r1")
```

where the CR moves the cursor to the start of the line, so it looks like

```
...syntax error: operand expected (error token is "
1")
```

where the second line is actually printed on top of the first.

Check the input your script gets, and see e.g. [How to remove carriage return and newline from a variable in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15520339/6372809)