# Executing Bash Command with Variable (Azure CLI)

Tags: bash, azure

I'm trying to update Azure AD App by executing the following command

Now first this is the result of echo of appId

[image]

now when i try to execute the update command:

[image]

now if i try the same command with the value inline it works as below:

[image]

I'm not sure what is wrong !, and why using a variable does not work but using inline value works, this is part of a long script so its important for me to utilize variables.

Any one faced this before ?

Comment: Could you try with enclosing in double quotes?

--id "#appId"

Comment: I tried that, and i get the same result!

Comment: Damn, well I guess all is lost gg

Comment: Where's `$appId` from? The second screenshot makes me think there's a carriage return in there. What do you see for `declare -p appId`?

Comment: "eclare -- appId="33991168-xxxx-4799-974b-f14d932f9e61

dont mind the number changing i keep trying so it keeps changing but same behavior...

Comment: $appId is the result of a previous command to create the application

Comment: You have a carriage return in that variable, look at how it's `"eclare` instead of `declare` – that's the missing closing double quote. See [How to remove carriage return from a variable in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15520339/3266847)

Comment: It becomes even more clear with `printf '%q\n' "$appId"`

Comment: this is the previous command:
appId=$(az ad app create --display-name "${clusterName}-aad-server" --identifier-uris "https://${clusterName}-aad-server" --query appId -o tsv)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BenJamin W reference, I had to change the command to:

```
az ad app update --id ${appId//$'\r'} --set groupMembershipClaims=All
```

This removed the $ and the newline at the end.