# Syntax error: invalid token operator (error token is "

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Doing a basic shell script I'm having trouble with getting the length of a file with curl and later dividing it, and the text:

> `syntax error: invalid token operator (error token is"`

keeps appearing.

Simplified code would be:

```
    head=$(curl -sI $dir | awk '/Content-Lenth/{print $2}') 
    res=$(($head/3))
```

I've been reading solutions to similar problems and they said removing the `\r` that the variable is probably having at its end, so I put this in the middle of the two lines, but the problem is still there:

```
head=${head//\r}
```

Any idea why this happens? Is it because of an `\r` character at the end? If it's the case, how to remove it?

Comment: Sounds vaguely like [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash); how exactly are you running this script? A DOS carriage return in your data could not produce a syntax error in your script (but you want `$'\r'` instead of just `\r`).

Comment: Show the complete error message.

Comment: @Barmar /3")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "

Comment: @tripleee I'm using bash and running it with source command

Comment: Maybe you ough to temporarily add `echo "$head"` after the first line so you can see what that variable actually contains.

Comment: Note btw.: `Content-Lenth` [sic] ... ...

Comment: @Roadowl I've been doing that, and it is a number but with a new line character because if i put some text after it appears in a new line, but i'm having difficulties to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your issue, which for me was indeed caused by a carriage return at the end of the value of `$head`.  That arises from the HTTP protocol specification: HTTP uses carriage return / newline sequences as line terminators (like DOS and Windows), and `awk` will not recognize the carriage return as whitespace.

Your attempt to remove the carriage return ...

> ```
> head=${head//\r}
> ```

... does not serve that purpose.  The `\` is a general escape character to the shell, preserving the literal meaning of whatever character follows.  Since the character `r` has no special significance to the shell, the above code is equivalent to

```
# Oops, not what you meant:
head=${head//r}
```

I used this alternative:

```
# Strip all non-digits:
head=${head//[^0-9]}
```

, and that resolved the issue for me.

Do also note, however, that

1. you have misspelled "Length", and
2. [HTTP header names are not case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259004/2402272), but by default, `awk` regular expressions are.  Therefore, your `awk` command might in some cases fail to match the wanted header even after the spelling is corrected.

Here's a version of your script that addresses all of these issues:

```
head=$(curl -sI "$dir" | awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} /Content-Length/{print $2}') 
head=${head//[^0-9]}
res=$(($head/3))
```

The last two lines could be merged into one, but I have kept them separate for clarity.  That might also serve well if you want to use the value of `$head` for other purposes, too.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520339/how-to-remove-carriage-return-from-a-variable-in-shell-script for how to remove CR from a variable.