# Later chars displaces previous chars in string concat and output

Tags: bash

I want to get the home directory of a GCP instance by

```
p=$(gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE_NAME -- 'echo ${HOME}')
```

Suppose the `p` equals to `/home/abc`.
Then I do a simple str concat and echo with

```
echo ${p}/xx
```

I would naturally expect

```
/home/abc/xx
```

Instead, it returns

```
/xxme/abc
```

Interesting enough, later chars `xx` displaces previous ones `ho`. How come? Any one with the fix?

Comment: Looks like you're getting dos style CRLF line endings mixed in somewhere.

Comment: Any way to strip them?

Comment: What version of `gcloud` are you using? If it's older than version 288.0.0, try upgrading and see if that helps.

Comment: `Google Cloud SDK 334.0.0
alpha 2021.03.26
beta 2021.03.26
bq 2.0.66
core 2021.03.26
gsutil 4.60`

Comment: Ok, not that then. `p=$(gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE_NAME -- 'echo ${HOME}' | dos2unix)` may help.

Comment: thx. But it needs to install extra `doc2unix`. Any native bash script?

Comment: Seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520339/how-to-remove-carriage-return-from-a-variable-in-shell-script/51675022

Answer (score 1):

I address it by using the `dos2unix` solution in the question comment:

```
p=$(gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE_NAME -- 'echo ${HOME}' | dos2unix)
```

, despite the extra dependency.

Comment: Another option that will _probably_ work if you don't want to install `dos2unix` is to replace `dos2unix` with `tr -d '\r'` - that is, remove all CR characters in the stream.