# Create curl delete request in a shell script loop

Tags: bash, loops, curl, request, html-lists

I have the following problem.
In the first curl query assigned to the `list_json`  variable, I get a list of objects in json format.
Then, based on the id's extracted from this list, I want to delete all the elements I retrieved.
My script unfortunately only works for the last element and as a result I have to repeat it n times to empty the whole list.

Why is this happening, where is the error occurring? I'll add that the same loop using `echo`  instead of `curl ...` correctly displays all urls with ids, which works as expected using postman. That means ids are available, so why are they not deleted?

My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

API_PATH="http://local:8080/api/elements"

list_json=$(curl -s $API_PATH)

for element_id in $(echo ${list_json[@]} | jq -r '.[].id')
do
curl -X DELETE ${API_PATH}${element_id}
done
```

Any hints welcome.
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

For beginners as I: I found a problem using `set -x` at the end of the script to see all called commands. There was `/r` added at the end of ids and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15520508/22167821) helped.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).